# Entity Framework Core 7: rewrite the query in a form that can be translated error when I use a an expression for collection

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I would like to use an expression to define a projection in my query, and I set conditions of in my query according of the parameters received from the user.

This is the expression:

```
private Expression<Func<MyDTO, MyDTO>> GetProjectionForSearch()
{
    return x => new MyDTO
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Property1 = x.Property1,
        Property2 = x.Property2,
    };
}
```

This is the query that it works:

```
return await _context.DbSet
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(GetProjectionForSearch())
    .ToListAsync();
```

However, I would like to set some filters according to the parameters that I receive from the user. Until now, I was using this way:

```
IQueryable<MyDTO> myIq = _context.DbSet
    .Select(GetProyeccionFacturaPorBusqueda());

if (param1 != null)
{
    myIq = myIq.where(x => x.Property1 == param1);
}

if (param2 != null)
{
    myIq = myIq.where(x => x.Property2 == param2);
}

return await myIq.ToListAsync();
```

But when I set the where conditions in this way, I get this error:

> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'

How could I use projection and set the where in a dynamic way?

Thanks

Comment: As an aside, do you have a good _evidence-based_ reason for using `AsNoTracking()`? (because it isn't a magic "_go-faster_" button: it has plenty of negative side-effects).

Comment: Your code using `IQueryable` with `myIq = myIq.Where( ... )` looks fine to me - but you'll get that error if the expressions you're using inside `Where( ... )` reference non-mapped properties or certain expressions - please post your **actual code** and confirm whether or not all property-expressions are mapped in EF or not.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a mapper like Automapper/Mapperly/Mapster.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDto>();
});
```

... then:

```
return await _context.DbSet
.ProjectTo<MyDto>(config)
.ToListAsync();
```

If there are customizations needed to the mapping such as flattening a related entity into a DTO column, you can use `ForMember()`:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => 
{
    cfg.CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDto>()
        .ForMember(x => x.SubjectName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Subject.Name));
});
```

This tells Automapper that to populate a SubjectName in the DTO, go to the entity's Subject property and get the name. Automapper can map these automatically by convention, though I generally opt to be specific to avoid surprises.

Using `ProjectTo()` will send the resulting expression down to SQL just like running a `Select` does, so there is no need to eager load related entities or use `AsNoTracking`. (As opposed to using `Map()` which will perform the mapping in memory)

Comment: Not the best `MapFrom` example. The default convention already does that :)

Comment: Yeah I mentioned that.. :)  I never use convention-based mappings, one reason is visibility into whether or not a setting is expected to be used if I make changes to the source then it flows through the re-mapping in the case I rename, or brings up a compiler error if I remove something that is mapped, rather than a runtime error if I rename or remove something and have the convention-based mapping break.

Comment: I can understand if you sometimes disable that convention, but otherwise, you're going against the auto thing. AM can only offer runtime validation, as in an unit test, maybe you want a mapper that generates code at build time.

Comment: Yeah, I have plans to look at Mapperly, but that doesn't help when I have projects already using Automapper. Automapper provides a nice mapping configuration syntax and builds the expressions for projection, so that is "auto" enough for me. I do use convention-based mappings for 1st-level members,